# Can't set conditional classes for IE on a server

Tags: html, css

I've included in my head section:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
```

Everything is fine when I open my site locally, html tag has class ie7(ie8) when I open it in IE7(IE8), but when I upload files on a server (which is on apache), and check it has an empty class. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Apache shouldn't be modifying your HTML, are you sure this isn't a caching issue?

Comment: I don't think so, I refreshed site cache many times

Comment: Ok, solved issue. It was my stupid mistake, conditional classes weren't loaded because on server I checked index.php, in which was included my local file. Sorry for this ;)